# simple_form_for and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have dumb question:

```
= simple_form_for :session, url: :sessions do |f|
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.button :submit, 'Sign in!'

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
end
```

It looks like I have no email and password in params, because in rails console everything works good. Can somebody explane me what does :session mean in my form and how can I get my email and passowrd?

Comment: A small tip: you can dump `params` into the browser by putting the following in the beginning of your `create` method `render :text => params.to_s and return`. It's likely you need to refer to `params[:session][:email]` and `params[:session][:password]`

Answer (score 1):

*(Moving this to an answer since it seems the majority agrees what I've suggested is the fix to the OP's issue)*

***A small tip:** you can dump `params` into the browser by putting the following in the beginning of your create method `render :text => params.to_s and return`.*

It's likely you need to refer to `params[:session][:email]` and `params[:session][:password]` in your `create` method.

A Symbol in the `form_for`'s first argument is [well documented](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for); see **Generic `form_for`**.